# How to map many columns from one table in database to one array/list in class?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, orm

I have a table in database which has some columns like year,name and also 12 columns (m1,m2,...,m12) representing months. I would like to map this table into one class using NHibernate, ideally, these 12 mapped columns would look like:

```
_mappedMonths[] = new double[12];
```

Has anyone a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to map the columns directly to an array, as you describe, take a look at the ICompositeUserType interface. You can find an article about custom NHibernate mapping [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100516024604/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/howard_dierking/archive/2007/04/23/nhibernate-custom-mapping-types.aspx), and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127202933/http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/05/87218.aspx) blog post might be of interest as well.

However, if it is not super important you might consider mapping the columns just as you normally would, but as private/protected properties, and then create a public property in your class that exposes those private/public properties as an array. That would be a simpler and faster solution, but would result in code that is not quite as clean.